# Get sequence of characters from words

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to generate a, unique code based on the input given.

```
Input = "ABC DEF GHI"
```

The code generated will be like,

**"ADG"** (first letter of each word) and if this exists then **"ABDG"** (first two letters of first word and first letter of rest of the words) this exists too then **"ABCDG"** next is **"ABCDEG"** and like wise if goes on till a unique code is generated. The validation is made thorough an API.

Types of input can be:

"ABC" (or)
"ABC DEF" (or)
"ABC DEF GHI" (or)
"ABC DEF GHI JKL"

I have tried like,

```
let count = 1;

    let val = this.userForm.get("name").value;
    let textArr = val.split(" ");

    let res;
  
      for(let i = 0; i< textArr.length; i++){
    
         res += textArr[i].substring(0,count)
      
      }
```

---

```
      let char1 = "", char2 = "", char3 = "";
       
       let ss:any = val.split(" ", 3);
      
       if(ss[0].length > 1)
         char1 = ss[0].substring(0,2)
    
       if(ss[1] && ss[1].length > 0)
         char2 = ss[1].substring(0,1)
    
       if(ss[2] && ss[2].length > 0)
         char3 = ss[2].substring(0,1)
    
    let result = char1 + char2 + char3;

   this.restApi.validateCode(result).subscribe((data: any) => {
     console.log(data) // returns boolean
    });
```

Couldn't get the logic what I want. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to generate your desire sequence in order.

```js
function generateCandidates(input)
{
  let candidates = [];
  //associate pointers for each word
  let words = input.split(" ").map(str => {return {str, ptr:1}}); 
  
  //First candidate
  let candidate = words.map(({str,ptr}) => str.substr(0,ptr)).join("");
  candidates.push(candidate);
  
  //find the first pointer that is still less than the length of the word
  let word;
  while( word = words.find(({str,ptr}) => ptr < str.length ) )
  {
    word.ptr++; //increment the pointer
    candidate = words.map(({str,ptr}) => str.substr(0,ptr)).join("");
    candidates.push(candidate);
  }
  
  return candidates;
}

console.log(generateCandidates("ABC"));
console.log(generateCandidates("ABC DEF"));
console.log(generateCandidates("ABC DEF GHI"));
console.log(generateCandidates("ABC DEF GHI JKL"));
```